# How can I delete a block that contains faulty JavaScript breaking the C5 interface?

Tags: javascript, concrete5

I was working on an HTML block in Concrete5 located in the footer. I made a javascript call - can't quite remember it, but I think it was referencing either jQuery or the Google Maps API. Anyway, now the block won't display and oddly enough, I am completely unable to modify/add/remove blocks now. I'm pretty sure it is because of the javascript call it is making, but I can't modify or delete the block to fix the issue.

What am I supposed to now? I tried disabling javascript in my browser but of course that won't let me modify the blocks either.

Comment: I've run into this problem (on legacy 5.7) and IIRC it seemed unfixable - I ended up having to delete the page. That stinks. I guess you *could* delete the offending block using the API, but that could be more work than recreating the page.

Comment: @Pekka웃 But if the block is in the footer, it means it affects every single page since the footer appears in all? And if I create a new page, won't it just copy the footer and have the same issue?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Actually, I'm curious about doing this using the API - if you could point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Comment: `But if the block is in the footer, it means it affects every single page since the footer appears in all?` ahh, I see I see! `I'm curious about doing this using the API` one sec, it should be in the docs... is this a global area? (If those still exist in 5.8+, all my installs are still 5.7).

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, it is a global area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know 5.8+ that well yet, but this may be unfixable from within the UI.

If the error is in a global area, your best bet might be opening the template, changing the area name where the global area is used and displayed, and recreating it from scratch.

You'd be looking for something like this:

```
$a = new GlobalArea("Footer Nav");
```

and change the global area's name, thus creating a new one.

If that's not an option, you may have to resort to deleting (or altering) the faulty block through the API.

In my experience, the easiest way to get a blank page that has C5 bootstrapped is [creating a custom Dashboard page:](https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/working-with-pages/single-pages/dashboard-pages)

> It's a common task for a Concrete5 developer to create their own Dashboard pages. Dashboard pages are just single pages located inside the "single_pages/dashboard" directory. Once they're added within that location, they automatically show up in the Dashboard.

Now, as to how to edit or delete the block inside the area, I don't have a complete recipe, but [this example page showing advanced area operations](https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/designing-for-concrete5/advanced-area-operations) should get you started.

The API documentation for `GlobalAreas` is [here](https://documentation.concrete5.org/api/class-Concrete.Core.Area.GlobalArea.html), for `Block` [here](https://documentation.concrete5.org/api/class-Concrete.Core.Block.Block.html) (notice the `delete()` / `deleteBlock()` methods.)

Comment: **You saved my life**, thank you so much man. I edited  the `footer.php` file and found the part it creates the GlobalAreas. I made a condition to check for its name (the faulty area is called Footer01) and replaced it with "Footer01_New".

Answer (score 1):

FYI although the solution marked as best works, it leaves data in the database that will stay there forever and forces you to change your area's name which might be ok once but not if it happens again and again.

Since that was an HTML block, the best way was to go to your database's interface, probably phpMyAdmin, go into the table "btContentLocal" and do a search for the faulty code you had entered in the HTML block then fix or delete it.

Like that you're back to normal, you don't leave stuff behind, and you can keep your area as it is